# How to increase PocketSphinx dictionary accuracy in android

Tags: android, speech-recognition, voice-recognition, cmusphinx, speech-synthesis

I work on android voice recognition app using Pocket Sphinx
this is a dictionary file. "grammar.corpus"

```
SHUTDOWN
START
STOP
REGISTER    PATH
REGISTER    LOCATION
WHERE   AM  I
YES
NO
TAKE    ME  TO
EMERGENCY
```

when I tested app, I got bad result, the recognizer return result by joining multi words from many line. e.g (it recognize "START PATH ME").

- How can I recognize block of sentence not individual words from multi line?
- How can I train recognizer to increase accuracy?
- How can I use jsgf instead lm?

thank you in advance

Answer (score 2):

> How can I recognize block of sentence not individual words from multi line?

Use JSGF grammar

> How can I train recognizer to increase accuracy?

http://cmusphinx.sourceforge.net/wiki/faq#qwhy_my_accuracy_is_poor

> How can I use jsgf instead lm?

Replace `-lm file.lm` with `-jsgf file.jsgf` in demo sources.